# Does Google penalize for H1 & H2 that are not human readable?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I was curious how a competitor's Web site was ranking so high for many of my keywords, especially since the company is located in another city. Looking through their source code I noticed at the top of every page the following coding was being used:

```
<div class="content"><h1 class="SEOnly">keyword, keyword, keyword, so on</h1>
<h2 class="SEOnly">keyword CITY, keyword CITY, keyword CITY, so on</h2>
```

The CSS class "SEOonly" reads "height:1px;" essentially making the text in both unreadable to Humans and the top of their content section clean, but Google is certainly indexing all of this.

Are either of these acceptable SEO that I should be implementing on my Website? I am using a Wordpress framework with my own custom theme, a fair amount of images with good ALT tags and a robust SEO plugin. However it appears these guys know a heck of a lot more than me.

Comment: Yes Google will penalize your website if you are using hidden text or links.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, google penalizes for hidden content.  You have found an example of this where the text is small to be legible, however the following techniques are also a problem

- text the same color as the background
- text positioned off the screen
- text that hidden using css display:none

You could report this site to Google.  They have a help document that explains how to do so http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93713

Comment: Thanks and I used your link to report this. I was already aware of your other points but never saw 'hidden' h1 & h2 before.

Comment: This CSS: h1.hidden {display:none;} will hide the h1 content and not take up any space on the page. Maybe you never "saw" hidden text because it was hidden!

Comment: A 1px is effectively as good as a hidden element. They are either penalized or it is ignored in the ranking process on that page.

Comment: Furthermore just because they are ranking, doesn't mean Google doesn't know about it. Such stunts can harm rankings but doesn't mean the page will be de-indexed. Focus on building content, and your beat them in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Google will penalize you for it.  See the Google Guidelines page one hiding text and/or links http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353.